# random integers reading and writing a file. Attempting to create multiple functions using a range 0,501

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, random, range

Im working on some python assignments for class and I cannot answer this question. I cannot find the error in my code. The error I receive is `TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable`. The question is:

**a**. Random Number File Writer Function
Write a function that writes a series of random numbers to a file called  "random.txt". Each random number should be in the range of 1 through 500. The function should take an argument that tells it how many random numbers to write to the file.

**b**. Random Number File Reader Function
Write another function that reads the random numbers from the file "random.txt", displays the numbers, then displays the following data:

The total of the numbers

The number of random numbers read from the file

**c**. Main Function
Write a main function that asks the user about how many  random number the user wants to generate. It them calls the function in a. with the number the user wants as an argument and generates random numbers to write to the file. Next, it calls the function in b.

Here is my code:

```
import random
def random_Write(num):
# Open a file  for writing 
    file_w = open('random.txt', 'w')
       
    for i in range(0,num):
        rand = random.randrange(1,501)
        file_w.write(str(rand) + '\n')
        #closing file
    file_w.close()
        
def random_Read():
# Reading from file
    readFile = open('random.txt', 'r')
    count = 0
    total = 0
    for lines in random_Read:
        count +=1
        total += float(lines)

        print ('number count: ', str(count))
        print ('The numbers add up to: ', str(total))
        readFile.close()

def main():
    num = int(input("How many numbers would you like to generate?: "))
    random_Write(num)
    random_Read()

main()
```

Comment: Your error is in this line:
```for lines in random_Read:```

random_read is a function (you have defined) but you are looping over it. In front of ```in``` in a for loop, you should put a list or an iterable object.

Comment: Hi thank you so much. I've adjusted that code but now I'm receiving the error 'I/O operation on closed file.'

Comment: Yeah. you need to readlines() from the file.

Comment: Thank you Amin, I appreciate your help. the code runs now!

Answer (score 0):

Quite simple actually, in random_Read(), in the for loop, instead of `for lines in random_Read:` put in `for lines in readFile.readlines():`  Why are you getting the error? because of a simple typo because you said random_Read which is the function...

Answer (score 0):

Your function random_Read has some mistakes. Here is a corrected version:

```
def random_Read():
#Reading from file
    readFile = open('random.txt', 'r')
    count = 0
    total = 0
    #You were looping with random_Read. I changed to readFile.readlines()
    #so you get a list with all of the lines of the file.
    for lines in readFile.readlines():
        count +=1
        total += float(lines)
        print ('number count: ', str(count))
        print ('The numbers add up to: ', str(total))
    #only call .close() once, at he end of the function
    readFile.close()
```

Comment: No problem, @Tim !